# org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document when tried to enter number

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to enter Account number in a text field which is given in below HTML. But, the entered number is removed completely when I debug and at times only last digits are entered and at times failing.

```
<input id="consumerNonew" name="consumerNonew" type="text" countchar="" length="10" display="true" setvallocal="" value="940" maxlength="10" ng-blur="click($event,{s:&quot;consumerNonew&quot;,e:&quot;blur&quot;,p:&quot;dewaPaymentInpForm&quot;});" autocomplete="off" class="  validate  is-invalid-input">
```

Below is the code.

```
public void dwshortname_and_Contract_number_is_entered() throws Throwable {

    Thread.sleep(5000);

    driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNamenew")).sendKeys("TestUser");
    Thread.sleep(5000);         
    WebElement Accnumber= driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNonew"));

    final int MAXIMUM_WAIT_TIME = 120;
    final int MAX_STALE_ELEMENT_RETRIES = 10;

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, MAXIMUM_WAIT_TIME);
    int retries = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("consumerNonew"))).click();

              Accnumber.sendKeys("2012269940");
            Accnumber.sendKeys(Keys.TAB); 

            break;

        //  

        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException e)
        {
            if (retries < MAX_STALE_ELEMENT_RETRIES)
            {
                retries++;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                throw e;
            }


        }               

         }


 }
```

Comment: Instead of storing WebElement and then Clicking on it (by using Id filter), then using stored WebElement again. Try to Clicking and then directly use Id filter and send keys. Instead of Storing.  Element becomes stale when you store web element --> perform action --> use stored element again..

Comment: I tried directly using the Id filter without storing the element. But seeing the same result.

Comment: Oh okay, then don't think it is generic issue. must be specific with your application. To debug, try entering one letter at a time with a delay of 2seconds between every letter, instead of entire string at a time.. This might help you figure out what exactly it is going through..

Comment: Ok. I'll try that.

Comment: I tried passing single number at a time. while in debug mode, everything is working fine. But, when I run the script, the first number entered is getting removed and second number is only displayed.

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNamenew")).sendKeys("TestUser");
  Thread.sleep(10000);      
  // driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNonew")).sendKeys("2012269940");
   driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNonew")).sendKeys("2");
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNonew")).sendKeys("0");
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNonew")).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);`

Comment: Have you heard of Robot Class? you can try it once and see if it works..

Comment: Nope. I haven't heard about Robot class.

Comment: If the below delay trick does not work, then we can try robot class. let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code for robot class:

```
Robot RoboKey = new Robot();
RoboKey.delay(2000);
RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
RoboKey.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
```

.
.
.

so on!

Comment: I did this at first only but it didn't work. I will try robot class and see if that works

Comment: Sure, hope the above example would help

Comment: hola! it worked :-) robot class. but my number has duplicate integers that is not entered though I mentioned it ... any thoughts ?

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.id("consumerNonew")).sendKeys("");//2012269940
  
  Robot robot = new Robot();  
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_6);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_9);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_4);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_0);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);`

Comment: oh you mean '9' and '2' are not entered?

Comment: Yes since those two are repeated. I see them skipped in the text box while running the script. wondering why ?

Comment: try using, robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_2);robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_2);   same with 9 also

Comment: Perfect!! it worked.. thanks a lot :)  :-) you made my day!!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: yeah again it is failing now.

Comment: Earlier, the robot class key events entered numbers in text field but failing at first key event. the numbers are not entered into text field.

Comment: is this code part of automation which would run as regression without any manual interaction?

Comment: Do you need any more info? regarding this question